# Can't side-load addin in Word 2021

Tags: office-addins, word-addins

I'm developing an add-in for Word, and so far it has worked, I was able to sideload the add-in by creating a network share & adding it as trusted catalog.
But after I made a small change to the manifest.xml it has stopped working. Under Insert => Add-in => Shared Folder it keeps showing "No add-ins currently available. "
I've tried a different share, a different manifest.xml from a different app, deleting the office cache, but it still doesn't work. It keeps showing "No add-ins currently available. "
I've clicked Refresh multiple times.
Very annoying.

I'm on Windows 11 and Office 2021.

Any ideas?